# Weird behaviour on ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, wpf-controls

I have created an applicatin that is able to register some users with an image. To list them, I show that images inside a `ListBox`, and then you can click on each user image to select it, as shown in this image.

[image]

This `ListBox` is using my own `Template`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="TiledListBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="80">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Picture}" Width="80" Height="80"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `ListBox` in `XAML`:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListObservableUsers, ElementName=SelectUser}" Style="{DynamicResource TiledListBox}" 
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" MouseDoubleClick="ListBoxUsers_MouseDoubleClick" />
```

Code behind only fills the `ListBox` items using an `ObservableCollection`.

The problem comes here. When I try to click on a user that it's different to the first one, more than one user is selected, as shown in this other picture:

[image]

Any idea on why that can be happening?

I have to say that I'm using the same code in another `Window` and it works perfectly, but I can't see any difference between them...

EDIT: You can use this code behind to make the example work.

```
 public partial class MainWindow
{
    public ObservableCollection<DtoObject> ListObservableUsers { get; set; } 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ListObservableUsers = new ObservableCollection<DtoObject>();
        InitializeComponent();

        Image image = new Image {Source = Extensions.LoadBitmap(new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.vaca))};
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            DtoObject dtoObject = new DtoObject {Picture = image};
            ListObservableUsers.Add(dtoObject);
        }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static BitmapSource LoadBitmap(Bitmap source)
    {
        IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
        BitmapSource bs = null;
        bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
        IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        return bs;
    }
}

public class DtoObject
{
    public Image Picture { get; set; }
}

private void ListBoxUsers_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    AcceptUser();
}    

private void AcceptUser()
    {
        if (ListBoxUsers.SelectedIndex < 0) return;

        selectedUser = (DtoObject)ListBoxUsers.SelectedItem;

        EventHandler handler = UserSelected;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new EventArgs());

        DialogResult = true;
        Close();
    }
```

The event goes in another `Window`, so I think the problem might not be here.

Comment: Try setting `SelectionMode` to `Single`

Comment: It's set to `Single`...

Comment: What does your code behind look like if any ..

Comment: It sounds almost like your SHIFT key is stuck... perhaps you have inadvertently put the Windows `StickyKeys` function on (by pressing SHIFT 5 times quickly)? This feature can be turned off via the Accessibility icon in the Windows Control Panel.

Comment: I don't think is that, as I can use the same `ResourceDictionary` on another `ListBox` and this one is working perfectly...

Comment: does the working listbox use the same images? Maybe try removing the `Image` tag and see if the behavior remains the same.

Comment: No, they don't use the same images. If I remove the `Image` tag they remain the same...

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example that demonstrates the problem? I can't reproduce when I take the code provided and remove the extra stuff.

Comment: I posted a code behind example that introduces 4 random images in the `ListBox`.

Comment: Please show the DoubleClick and SelectionChanged event handlers you used in your ListBox.

Comment: Sure. I deleted the `SelectionChanged` one as it does anything. Updated code. Thanks!

Comment: Your code makes no sense. I had to change a lot of stuff just to start it, and then i couldn't reproduce the behavior. First you assigning an Image to an ImageSource, that can't work. In your example you use DtoObject and DtoUser, but DtoUser is unknown. Also why are you using System.Drawing for loading images? Wpf is perfectly capable of doing that on its own. Please provide a small completely buildable example of your problem. Otherwise ... its not a bug, its a problem with your machine.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to separate some code from the original as the code I'm using is a bit extense and I forgot to change some names...